# Any boto3 sns methods for adding subscribers into a topic etc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am looking to build a lambda script, where I will be able to:

1. List all the SNS topics that I have currently
2. Compare with a list/database/table to see if any topics are not in the existing list
3. Create the topics
4. Add subscribers into them
5. Track their subscription status
6. Once confirmed, send them the very last SNS notification

On a very rough level, I can accomplish some of the above tasks with the following methods:

1. import boto3 -> list_topics()
2. parse value from parameter store to obtain a dictionary of topic_name and topic_arn as key-value pair. Compare with the result of list_topic()
3. create_topic()
4. ???
5. list_subscriptions()/list_subscriptions_by_topic()
6. ???

Does anyone know how I can accomplish step 4 and 6?

For step 6, I am thinking of having eventbridge to trigger the notification-generating lambda script whenever a new subscriber is added to topic, but not sure if its doable and also the fact that the existing subscribers will be notified again.

For step 4 I am completely clueless.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a subscriber to a topic with boto3, see docs here:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.subscribe
And if you wont to send something out to that topic you publish to it, see docs here:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For step 6, my goal is actually to send new subscribers  the latest email that existing subscribers receive. For example, if my lambda sends an email with the message="It is 8am in the morning" at 8AM in the morning, and someone subscribes to the topic at 9am, I want that person to receive the very last notification of the topic, which is an email notification saying "It is 8am in the morning". However, I don't want it to be a lambda trigger, as this will result in old joiners receiving that email again.

Comment: I dont think this can be done with just sns. YOu have to build more logic into this in this case. You can have a second lambda thats gets triggered on new subscribers and have the last email saved somewhere and when just send that email to the latest sub.